# Send message as user alias

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email, model-view-controller, gmail-api

**Is there a way to use the Gmail API to send as one of the provided users aliases instead of the users direct email?**

I have a general user in my Google Org and it has a few aliases such as `help@example.com`, `support@example.com` which all belong to `generaluser@example.com`

At the moment it sends fine but different sections of my app need to send email as the specified alias.

Below is my code which sends email as the specified user without error.

```
private static async Task<GmailService> GetAuthorizedGmailService()
    {
        var serviceAccountEmail = "serviceaccount@gserviceaccount.com";
        string AuthFile = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("");
        X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(AuthFile,"", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
        ServiceAccountCredential credential;

        credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
        {
            User = "user@email.com",
            Scopes = Scopes
        }.FromCertificate(certificate));

        GmailService service = null;

        if (await credential.RequestAccessTokenAsync(CancellationToken.None))
        {
            service = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            });
        }
        return service;
    }
```

The above is my code for creating my GmailService and below is my execution of the SendRequest:

```
var mimeMessage = MimeKit.MimeMessage.CreateFromMailMessage(mail);

var gmailMessage = new Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data.Message
{
    Raw = Encode(mimeMessage.ToString())
};

var service = await GetAuthorizedGmailService();
UsersResource.MessagesResource.SendRequest request = service.Users.Messages.Send(gmailMessage, "user@email.co.za");
await request.ExecuteAsync();
```

Anyone know how I can specify which alias should be used in the from address?

I have tried setting it in the from section of the HTTP header and I still get the message from the users direct email address. I would very much like to not have to create a user account for each of these alias just so I can send as the appropriate email address.

Comment: It should work if you just change the `From` header in your message, e.g. `From: support@example.com` as long as it is an alias.

Comment: Unfortunately it hasn't worked for me. I have read the request header and made sure the from address was one of the aliases assigned to the user but it still came through as the primary email of the user. Is it maybe a setting in the users profile or maybe the Scope header? because at the moment all I am allowing is https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment made by [Tholle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3617886/tholle) was correct. Adding the alias in the From header makes it use the alias.

The problem I was having is while the user had the alias assigned to them you have to also add it to the Send mail as in the users Gmail Settings.

All I had to do was go add the alias there and then it didn't override the From header with the users primary address.

Setting is located in: Settings > Acounts > Send mail as: